# Hardware Timestamping using PTP

Tags: linux, ethernet, timestamps, intel

I'm new to Linux programming. I have an Intel NIC with e1000e driver. I'm working on accurate time stamping of packets being captured from a network.

1. My question is if I want to use RT Linux how can I increase the priority of the time stamping thread. Is this possible?
2. I read about how to work with PTP IEEE 1588. My Intel NIC is capable of hardware timestamping. Thing is I'm not sure it would work in my setup. I have a Transmitter ( which is a micro-controller from mbed with no OS). Then I have a receiver which is a normal Linux machine with an Intel NIC and e1000e. I can only get the packets to be hardware time stamped at the receiver when the transmitter could build packets with PTP. But I think my micro-controller API's do not have that support for PTP.

Can I still hardware time stamp the packets?

Comment: What NIC are you using exactly?

Answer (score 3):

I am not too sure why you are thinking of having a *"timestamping thread"*, in my understanding the kernel will need to set-up the driver to enable hardware timestamping and then you run a PTP daemon of choice *([ptpd](http://ptpd.sourceforge.net/), [open-avb-gptp](https://github.com/intel-ethernet/Open-AVB/tree/master/daemons/gptp), [linuxptp](http://linuxptp.sourceforge.net/))* to implement the clock synchronisation protocol itself.

On the mbed side, there is currently no API that you can utilise, but I have started [discussion on the list](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/mbed-devel/zEQMpSEDE7Y/Clr-7I3xBwQJ) which you should probably join.